# karate-gatling report aggregation

Tags: api, gatling, karate

One question as just starting to use karate-gatling: is it possible to aggregate the reports generated? So after multiple runs to get one single report? It would be nice to be able to compare somehow the performance - to get automatically the information if there is a performance degradation or not. What I did try but did not work, was to copy the simulation logs and afterwards only generate the reports ("gatling.bat -ro simulations") but this did not work. The error that I got was:
gatling.bat -ro simulations/catskaratesimulation-1544015145031
GATLING_HOME is set to "D:\AutomationTeam\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.0.1.1"
JAVA = ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe""
Parsing log file(s)...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "catskaratesimulation"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong(StringLike.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong$(StringLike.scala:305)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:29)
        at io.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader.$anonfun$firstPass$1(LogFileReader.scala:102)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
        at io.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader.firstPass(LogFileReader.scala:86)
        at io.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader.$anonfun$x$4$1(LogFileReader.scala:125)
        at io.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader.parseInputFiles(LogFileReader.scala:63)
        at io.gatling.charts.stats.LogFileReader.(LogFileReader.scala:125)
        at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.initLogFileReader(RunResultProcessor.scala:67)
        at io.gatling.app.RunResultProcessor.processRunResult(RunResultProcessor.scala:49)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:81)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:46)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:38)
        at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)

Is there another way to do it? Should I somehow reconfigure gatling? Thanks!

Comment: I'm the author of Karate - and I have no idea about this :( - I just know that there is a gatling tool you can use to aggregate reports

Comment: @PeterThomas thank! I will keep searching

Comment: @PeterThomas Now we want to upgrade to karate 0.9.3 and we are again having problems. When having version 0.9.0 we used gatling.plugin.version 2.2.4 as after having the simulation files we needed to get a trend report (done with this gatling-report cmd: java -jar gatling-report-3.0-20180530.140113-7-capsule-fat.jar simulation1_1.log simulation2_2.log -o _output). Now when upgrading to 0.9.3 we cannot use gatling 2.2.4; we need to use 3.x and with these simul files the gatling-report tool fails to generate the report.
Is there any way to do this by using the latest karate and gatling versions?

Comment: yes we upgraded to Gatling 3.X in 0.9.2 https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.2 - I'm sorry I have no idea how to answer your question :( you can try ask a new one and tag it as Gatling, and maybe you need to post your question on the Gatling project / issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when using the same version (2.2.4) via gatling.bat -ro folder_with_simulations.